# Highcharts tooltip using HTML allows advanced formatting like images

Tags: highcharts

I am looking for a sample of Javascript code to visualise pictures in a tooltip of a pie chart from Highcharts.

I would like to see different pictures according to the sectors I am navigating on...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

According to the docs, the [`tooltip.formatter`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) is:

> ... a subset of HTML. Unless [`useHTML`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.useHTML) is true, the HTML of the tooltip is parsed and converted to SVG, therefore this isn't a complete HTML renderer. The following tags are supported: `<b>`, `<strong>`, `<i>`, `<em>`, `<br/>`, `<span>`.
>    Spans can be styled with a `style` attribute, but only text-related CSS that is shared with SVG is handled.

So you should set tooltip like this:

```js
tooltip: {
  useHTML: true,
  formatter: function () {
    return '<b>' + this.point.name + "</b>: " + this.point.percentage + "%<br/>" + 
           "<img src='" + this.point.img + "'></img>";
  }
},
```

#### Here's a demo in Stack Snippets

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Favorite Fruits'
    },
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      formatter: function () {
        return '<b>' + this.point.name + "</b>: " + this.point.percentage + "%<br/>" + 
               "<img src='" + this.point.img + "'></img>";
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Fruits',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Apple',
            y: 50,
            img: "https://i.imgur.com/MmK9Xkc.png"
        }, {
            name: 'Banana',
            y: 25,
            img: "https://i.imgur.com/0G6GXWf.png"
        }, {
            name: 'Orange',
            y: 15,
            img: "https://i.imgur.com/Dv4KoD5.png"
        }, {
            name: 'Watermelon',
            y: 10,
            img: "https://i.imgur.com/2LN8PfD.png"
            
        }, ]
    }]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/6.1.2/css/highcharts.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/6.1.2/highcharts.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: `useHTML` no longer works  - your tooltips are being rendered as svg today on 4/24/2019

Comment: @steampowered, I could be wrong, but I think this is covered in my answer...* "the HTML of the tooltip is parsed and converted to SVG"* which uses *"a subset of HTML"*.  The docs for [`tooltip.useHTML`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.useHTML) don't seem to suggest it's deprecated.  Are you running into issues somewhere?  The runnable demo in this answer still seems to be working?

Comment: I ran your code snippet again today and found the tooltips are still SVG.  I first discovered this issue when I updated highcharts and tooltip anchor links stopped working.  There is no fix I can find, so I think highcharts stopped supporting HTML in favor of SVG without documenting.  `useHTML: true` has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

You can use tootlip formatter and useHTML, then return your cusomisted content, including images.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter